# How do i show Processing wheel in Jquery when we click on Search button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

when i click on  search button i need to show Processing Wheel in  Jquery .Is there any method available to show that.

Comment: Do you want to replace the button with a loading gif? Does the button click invoke an ajax call....etc

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, create a div on the page with the loading .gif in it.

```
$('#loading').hide();

$('#loading').ajaxStart(function() {
  $(this).show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

You could always replace the show and hide for fadeIn and fadeOut too.

Edit: Another method is to show the div when the button is clicked, then make the ajax call and use the success function to hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery ajax to load search results? If so you can use [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) methods to show and hide animation.